# I am getting this error while installing npm

Tags: npm-install

F:\Hcheckup2.0>npm install
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.5.1: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated ckeditor@4.7.3: We have renamed the @ckeditor package. New versions are available under the @ckeditor4 name.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated json3@3.3.2: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular/web-animations-js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-01-07T04_33_32_195Z-debug.log

Comment: Which command are you trying execute?

Answer (score 0):

update your core-js with this command
  npm install --save core-js@^3

also read https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/25/react-v15.6.2.html this you will get better things.

Answer (score -1):

The error is related to [web-animations.js](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js). Can you try removing and adding the package.json reference for this library. Also more information about your package contents will be helpful.